# How to use functions in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, openssl

I have a file which has hashes of the files against their filename.
For example,

```
fb7e0a4408e46fd5573ffb9e73aec021a9dcf426235c0ccfc37d2f5e09a68a23 /path/to/some/file
237e0a4408e46fe3573f239e73aec021a9dcf426235c023fc37d2f5e09a68a12 /path/to/another/file
... and so on...
```

I need the hash converted to `base64` encoded format.

So I used combination of a bash function and `awk`.

Here is what I wrote,

```
#!/bin/sh
base64Encode() {
     $1 | openssl base64 -A
}
awk ' { t = base64Encode $1; print t } ' file.txt
```

But it does not seem to work. I'm using `hashdeep` to generate the hash-list file and `hashdeep` does not support `base64` encoded output. That is why I'm using `openssl`.

Any help or tips regarding this would be great!

Edit:

The given answers work but I'm having some other issue it seems.

Usually `cat filename | openssl dgst -sha256 | openssl base64 -A` gives a `base64` encoded output for `filename` file which is absoutely correct,
and output from `hashdeep` matched output from `cat filename | openssl dgst -sha256`.
So, I thought of piping the output obtained from above step to `openssl base64 -A` for `base64` output. But, still I get different values from actual result.

Although this might be suited for a separate question perhaps, but still I would appreciate any support on this.

Comment: What output are you expecting? Do you not need the filename?

Comment: @123 I would use the filename but I can't make `base64` encoding work. This is just a demo code.

Comment: awk is not shell. You can't call a shell function from an awk script any more than you could call a C function from an awk script or vice-versa. In this case the awk script is doing absolutely nothing for you compared to just calling your shell function from shell so - is there any reason not to just do that?

Comment: This works but what I'm doing still has errors.
Usually `cat filename | openssl dgst -sha256 | openssl base64 -A` gives a `base64` encoded output for `filename` file which is absoutely correct,
and output from `hashdeep` matched output from `cat filename | openssl dgst -sha256`.
So, I thought of piping the output obtained from above step to `openssl base64 -A` for `base64` output. But, still I get different values from actual result.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @kmkaplan That question was posted by me as this question wasn't phrased quite properly, as I mentioned in the edit too.

Comment: @jww Agreed. Can this question be moved to proper location after it has been posted at Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Awk only:

```
$ awk '{ c="echo " $1 "|openssl base64 -A"
         c | getline r
         print r }' file
ZmI3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZkNTU3M2ZmYjllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwY2NmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGEyMwo=
MjM3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZlMzU3M2YyMzllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwMjNmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGExMgo=
```

For the tight one-liner version see @123's comment below.

... and @EdMorton's super-tight (read: super-proof) version.

Comment: Could just do `awk '{ "echo " $1 "|openssl base64 -A" | getline}1' file`

Comment: @123 Sure, but it looked SO undescriptive my eyes that I had to break it down.

Comment: @123 no because then you can't trivially close the pipe with `close(c)`. James - remember to test for getline success and close the pipe (`if ( (c | getline line) > 0 ) r = line; else r = "N/A"; close(c)`) but of course awk is doing nothing for you in this case so you wouldn't really use it in such a simple application, you'd just use a shell script.

Comment: @EdMorton Why do you need to trivially close the pipe?

Comment: In general you have to close the pipe so the process for the command on the right of it can terminate when it's input stream closes and so you can't get a "too many pipes open" failure so you have 2 choices: a) `c="echo " $1 "|openssl base64 -A"; c | getline r; close(c)` or b) `"echo " $1 "|openssl base64 -A" | getline r; close("echo " $1 "|openssl base64 -A")`. Obviously `a` is preferable so you don't risk NOT closing the pipe if you get a space character in the wrong place or have some other difference between the command string and the close string.

Answer (score 1):

Because you especially asking for *how to use functions*, I divided the problem to several small functions. It is a good practice in all (bigger) bash programs.

The basic rule is: functions behaves like any other commands:

- you can redirect their input/output
- you can call them with arguments
- and like.

The best functions are like common unix executables, e.g. reads from stdin and prints to stdout. This allows you use them in pipelines too.

So, now the rewrite:

```
# function for create base64 - reads from stdin, writes to stdout
base64Encode() {
        openssl base64 -A
}

# function for dealing with your file
# e.g. reads lines "hash path" and prints "base64 path"
convert_hashes() {
        while read -r hash path; do
                b64=$(base64Encode <<< "$hash")
                echo "$b64 $path"
        done
}

#the "main" program
convert_hashes < your_file.txt
```

output

```
ZmI3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZkNTU3M2ZmYjllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwY2NmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGEyMwo= /path/to/some/file
MjM3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZlMzU3M2YyMzllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwMjNmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGExMgo= /path/to/another/file
```

Yes, i know, i want only the `base64` without the attached path. Ot course, you can modify the above `convert_hashes` and remove the path from the output, e.g. instead of the `echo "$b64 $path"` you could use the `echo "$b64"` and the output will be just the `b64` string only - **but** youre loosing information in the function - which string belongs to which path - imho, not the best practice.

Therefore, you can leave the function as-is, and use another tool, for getting the first column - and only when needed - e.g. in the "main" program. This way you have designed a function for later more universal way.

```
convert_hashes < your_file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

output

```
ZmI3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZkNTU3M2ZmYjllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwY2NmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGEyMwo=
MjM3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZlMzU3M2YyMzllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwMjNmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGExMgo=
```

Now imagine, that you extending the script, and want not use files, but the input is coming from another program: Let simulate this with the following `get_data` function (of course, in the real app it will do something other, not just `cat`:

```
get_data() {
cat <<EOF
fb7e0a4408e46fd5573ffb9e73aec021a9dcf426235c0ccfc37d2f5e09a68a23 /path/to/some/file
237e0a4408e46fe3573f239e73aec021a9dcf426235c023fc37d2f5e09a68a12 /path/to/another/file
EOF
}
```

now you can use the all above as:

```
get_data | convert_hashes
```

the output will be the same as above.

of course, you can do something with the output too, let say

```
get_data | convert_hashes | grep another/file | cut -d ' ' -f1
MjM3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZlMzU3M2YyMzllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwMjNmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGExMgo=
```

Of course, if you have such "modular" structure, you can easily replace any parts, without need touch the other parts, let say going to replace the `openssl` with the `base64` command.

```
base64Encode() {
        base64
}
```

And everything will continue work, without any other changes. Of course, in real app is (probably) pointless to have function which calls only one program - but I especially doing this because you asked about the functions.

Otherwise, the above could be done in simple:

```
while read -r hash path; do
    openssl base64 -A <<<"$hash"
    echo
    #or echo $(openssl base64 -A <<<"$hash")
    #or printf "%s\n" $(openssl base64 -A <<<"$hash")
done < your_file.txt
```

or even

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 base  | xargs -I% -n1 bash -c 'echo $(openssl base64 -A <<<"%")'
```

You need the `echo` or `print` because the `openssl` doesn't prints newlines by default. Output:

```
ZmI3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZkNTU3M2ZmYjllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwY2NmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGEyMwo=
MjM3ZTBhNDQwOGU0NmZlMzU3M2YyMzllNzNhZWMwMjFhOWRjZjQyNjIzNWMwMjNmYzM3ZDJmNWUwOWE2OGExMgo=
```

*Ps: to be honest, i do not understand why do you need base64 encode some already encoded hash - but YMMV. :)*

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer!

Comment: @Ozil no problem, enjoy - just still not understand what do you want achieve...